# Visual C++ good way to do deep copy?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, copy, deep-copy

I have a struct something like this

```
struct
{
  struct bar x;
}foo

struct
{
  DWORD count;
  MyType* arr;
}bar
```

now I want to do a deep copy of an instance of `foo`, I am looking at a function from msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366535(v=vs.85).aspx) called


`void CopyMemory(
  In  PVOID Destination,
  In  const VOID *Source,
  In  SIZE_T Length
);`

While I don't think this will do a deep copy for me, what will be a good way to do a safe deep copy in this case?

Comment: If you're in C++, just define a copy-constructor for `bar`. It is, after all, it's responsibility to properly obey the Rule of Three. Even better, replace `bar` with `std::vector<MyType>`, because this wheel is already invented.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to create a copy constructor function, where you will assign each variable from the source object to the destination object. For pointers, use `new` keyword to allocate memory to store the object, rather than just copying the address of the object.

For more reference about copy constructor, refer to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_copy_constructor.htm